# Can I simulate LoRa technology using Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, lora

I have already implemented a scenario using Omnet++ and Veins framework. I need to simulate my scenario with LoRa technology.

Is there an implementation of Lora in Omnet++ ?

Otherwise, can I use LoRaSim with Omnet++?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answers are not really and no :D

Regarding the second no, the LoRaSim project uses Python scripts, no way to run those with OMNeT++.

As for the first "not really", there is a [Github repository](https://github.com/z1gm4/LoRa-Sim) with an apparent OMNeT++ LoRa model, but I am not sure if it is really working or reproducing the LoRa standard (PHY and MAC) completely. 
Maybe something to look further into though.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your reply.